# py.test: Temporary folder for the session scope

Tags: python, pytest

The `tmpdir` fixture in py.test uses the `function` scope and thus isn't available in a fixture with a broader scope such as `session`. However, this would be useful for some cases such as setting up a temporary PostgreSQL server (which of course shouldn't be recreated for each test).

Is there any clean way to get a temporary folder for a broader scope that does not involve writing my own fixture and accessing internal APIs of py.test?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately <s>there is currently no way (2014) of doing this nicely</s>.  [In the future](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050261/913098) py.test will introduce a new "any" scope or something similar for this, but that's the future.

Right now you have to do this manually yourself.  However as you note you lose quite a few nice features: symlinks in /tmp to the last test, auto cleanup after a few test runs, sensibly named directories etc.  If the directory is not too expensive I usually combine a session and function scoped fixture in the following way:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_dir(request):
    temp_dir = py.path.local(tempfile.mkdtemp())
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: folder.remove(rec=1))
    # Any extra setup here
    return temp_dir

@pytest.fixture
def temp_dir(session_dir, tmpdir):
    session_dir.copy(tmpdir)
    return tmpdir
```

This creates a temporary directory which gets cleaned up after a test run, however for each test which actually needs it (by requesting `temp_dir`) gets a copy which is saved with the tmpdir semantics.

If tests actually need to share state via this directory then the finalizer of `temp_dir` would have to copy things back to the `session_dir`.  This is however not a very good idea since it makes the tests reliant on the execution order and would also cause problems when using pytest-xdist.

Comment: Would we run into any trouble if we simply copied the built-in tmpdir to a new plugin name, and scope it as we like?

Comment: Probably, IIRC the name of the tmpdir depends on the function scope and that might start to cause trouble.  But I haven't checked, try it if you like!

Comment: Since 2.8, this is no longer the case. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050261/384617.

Answer (score 41):

Since pytest release 2.8 and above the session-scoped `tmpdir_factory` fixture is available. See the example below from the [documentation](https://pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#tmp-path-factory).

```
# contents of conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def image_file(tmpdir_factory):
    img = compute_expensive_image()
    fn = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data').join('img.png')
    img.save(str(fn))
    return fn

# contents of test_image.py
def test_histogram(image_file):
    img = load_image(image_file)
    # compute and test histogram
```

Comment: To use the base temporary directory directly, instead of creating a sub-directory 'data', use the undocumented: `tmp_path_factory.getbasetemp()`.

Answer (score 1):

I add a *finalizer* when I want to **delete all temporary folders** created in session.

```
_tmp_factory = None
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def tmp_factory(request, tmpdir_factory):
    global _tmp_factory
    if _tmp_factory is None:
        _tmp_factory = tmpdir_factory
        request.addfinalizer(cleanup)
    return _tmp_factory

def cleanup():
    root = _tmp_factory.getbasetemp().strpath
    print "Cleaning all temporary folders from %s" % root
    shutil.rmtree(root)

def test_deleting_temp(tmp_factory):
    root_a = tmp_factory.mktemp('A')
    root_a.join('foo.txt').write('hello world A')

    root_b = tmp_factory.mktemp('B')
    root_b.join('bar.txt').write('hello world B')

    for root, _, files in os.walk(tmp_factory.getbasetemp().strpath):
        for name in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

The output should be like:

```
/tmp/pytest-of-agp/pytest-0/.lock
/tmp/pytest-of-agp/pytest-0/A0/foo.txt
/tmp/pytest-of-agp/pytest-0/B0/bar.txt
Cleaning all temporary folders from /tmp/pytest-of-agp/pytest-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. It looks like pytest doesn't remove temporary directories after test runs. The following is a regular function-scoped fixture.

```
# conftest.py
TMPDIRS = list()

@pytest.fixture
def tmpdir_session(tmpdir):
    """A tmpdir fixture for the session scope. Persists throughout the session."""
    if not TMPDIRS:
        TMPDIRS.append(tmpdir)
    return TMPDIRS[0]
```

And to have persistent temporary directories across modules instead of the whole pytest session:

```
# conftest.py
TMPDIRS = dict()

@pytest.fixture
def tmpdir_module(request, tmpdir):
    """A tmpdir fixture for the module scope. Persists throughout the  module."""
    return TMPDIRS.setdefault(request.module.__name__, tmpdir)
```

Edit:
Here's another solution that doesn't involve global variables. pytest 1.8.0 introduced a `tmpdir_factory` fixture that we can use:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def tmpdir_module(request, tmpdir_factory):
    """A tmpdir fixture for the module scope. Persists throughout the module."""
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp(request.module.__name__)


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def tmpdir_session(request, tmpdir_factory):
    """A tmpdir fixture for the session scope. Persists throughout the pytest session."""
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp(request.session.name)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `scope='session'` and `scope='module'` instead of messing around with global variables?

Comment: About the not removing part, it's semi-true: It keeps the last 3 temp dirs around, which is mentioned somewhere in the docs, i.e. it's a feature.

Comment: You can't use scope='session' or 'module' when you're using the tmpdir builtin fixture. You get an exception telling you you're trying to use a function-scoped fixture within a session/module scope fixture. Hence this workaround.

Comment: Ah right... now that you mention it I remember running into the same problem. I'd probably try to run the original `tempdir` code in a custom fixture...